# Jackson 3.1.1 Missing Type ID of Subtype Exception for Polymorphic Type of List?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a concrete object of an abstract class that I've made.

I'm using annotations on the abstract class and the daughter class, but the JSON output doesn't look right and I keep getting an exception on deserialiation.

I'm still learning Jackson, and unfortunatly a lot of the tutorials on the subject are outdated.

Here are the classes with my object mapper at the bottom:

**Abstract Class:**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "BTRFSPhysicalLocationItem")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(name = "Snapshot", value = Snapshot.class),
    @Type(name = "Backup", value = Backup.class),
    @Type(name = "Subvolume", value = Subvolume.class)})
public abstract class BTRFSPhysicalLocationItem {

    private final String name;
    @JsonProperty
    private final Path location;

    /**
     * Makes a new subvolume instance with the specified location. May or may
     * not actually exist.
     *
     * @param location The location of the subvolume
     */
    @JsonCreator
    protected BTRFSPhysicalLocationItem(@JsonProperty(value = "location") Path location) {
        this.location = location;
        this.name = location.getFileName().toString();
    }
```

**Concrete Class:**

```
public class Subvolume extends BTRFSPhysicalLocationItem {

    /**
     * Creates a new subvolume with the specified path.The subvolume may or may
     * not exist at this point.
     *
     * @param location
     */
    @JsonCreator
    public Subvolume(@JsonProperty Path location) {
        super(location);
    }
```

**Objectmapper block:**

```
ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
List<Subvolume> SUBVOLUME_LIST = new ArrayList<>();
//Subvolume is populated by other methods it's not worth showing them here
System.out.println("\n\n");
                MAPPER.writeValue(System.out, SUBVOLUME_LIST);
                System.out.println("\n\n\n");
                var s = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(SUBVOLUME_LIST);
                List<Subvolume> list = MAPPER.readValue(s, new TypeReference<List<Subvolume>>() {
                });
```

**Output JSON:** `[{"name":"WanderingEcho","location":"file:///home/sarah/NetBeansProjects/WanderingEcho/"}]`

Exception:

```
Aug 05, 2019 4:55:14 PM com.protonmail.sarahszabo.wanderingecho.btrfs.BTRFS <clinit>
SEVERE: null
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.protonmail.sarahszabo.wanderingecho.btrfs.subvolume.Subvolume]: missing type id property 'BTRFSPhysicalLocationItem'
 at [Source: (String)"[{"name":"WanderingEcho","location":"file:///home/sarah/NetBeansProjects/WanderingEcho/"}]"; line: 1, column: 89] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Other answers such as [Jackson deserialization of polymorphic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609032/jackson-deserialization-of-polymorphic-types) suggest using the `ObjectMapper` methods, but according to the tutorials I've read, this shouldn't be necessary.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong with the annotations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `json` you are missing the `BTRFSPhysicalLocationItem` - just think about it - how Jackson should know what implementation do you expect?

It should look like

```
[
    {
        "BTRFSPhysicalLocationItem": "Subvolume",
        "name": "WanderingEcho",
        "location":"file:///home/sarah/NetBeansProjects/WanderingEcho/"
    }
]
```

if you want Jackson to include the type when serializing the object you also need to add `JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY` as `include` as a parameter of `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation like

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "BTRFSPhysicalLocationItem")
```

---

**EDIT** ok seems that I figured this out - your problem with not generating properties is connected to Java type erasure and well described [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/336).

tldr; Jackson has problem with underestanding type - seems `List<Subvolume>` for him does not providing the type of elements. Because he doesn't know the type he won't serialize it

The solution is to create a helper class that will extends `ArrayList<Subvolume>` like

```
public class SubvolumeList extends ArrayList<Subvolume> {}
```

---

Additionaly you have a few issues in your code - one is that you should use `use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME` in `@JsonTypeInfo` if you want to deserialize by property value (like `Subvolume`) not by package/class string literal

Second is that you should name `@JsonProperty` on `@JsonCreator` parameter list like `@JsonProperty(value = "location")`

Comment: Yes, I saw that as well, but I'm not sure why the annotations don't generate that. I would think that the `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "BTRFSPhysicalLocationItem")` would have made that part. According to a website that I read, `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY` is the default selection if not explicitly noted.

Comment: you forget about `include` - I edited answer (by default I believe it is being set to `NONE`)

Comment: Just changed it, same error. Also, same output JSON string.

Comment: can you provide generated json?

Comment: `[{"name":"WanderingEcho","location":"file:///home/sarah/NetBeansProjects/WanderingEcho/"}]` The annotation is set to: `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "BTRFSPhysicalLocationItem")

`

Comment: as you see it still missing the `BTRFSPhysicalLocationItem` property

Comment: Yep. I need to figure out why the annotations are insufficient for serialization.

Comment: Yep, just checked, it ran just fine. Strange solution though. Maybe reified generics wasn't such a good idea after all.

Answer (score 0):

When I stumbled on this post, I was having a similar problem. I had

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = Id.MINIMAL_CLASS,
  property = "@class"
)
public class MyClass {
  public int myInt;
}
```

and then

```
public class MyIntWrapper {
  public Optional<MyInt> maybeMyInt;
}
```

I wanted to send `MyIntWrapper` over the wire. It was serializing the instances correctly into the JSON, but there was a deserialization issue. I was seeing

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.coder34.MyIntWrapper$Json]: missing type id property '@class' (for POJO property '#temporary-name')
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.coder34.MyIntWrapper$Json["maybeMyInt"])
```

Following @m.antkowicz link about type erasure, I tried adding it to the field. So I removed the annotation from `MyClass` and added it to the field `maybeMyInt` -

```
public class MyClass {
  public int myInt;
}
```

```
public class MyIntWrapper {
  @JsonTypeInfo(
    use = Id.MINIMAL_CLASS,
    property = "@class"
  )
  public Optional<MyInt> maybeMyInt;
}
```

and it worked.